# How to save a type from @types in a node module

Tags: typescript

My problem stems from the following scenario:

I am working on package A in Typescript. I have written package B in Typescript as well, which will be added as a dependency in package A.

Package B makes use of two javascript modules (C & D) and directly imports the types from their respective @types libraries (@types/C and @types/D).

While package B can build because it has the @types in the dev dependencies, package A will not as it will complain it has no definition of C and D in its own dependencies.

Is there any way to have it so that A will build, but with the following constraints:

1. A will not have the types of C and D as dev dependencies
2. B will not include the types as non-dev dependencies
3. `noImplicitAny` has to be set to true in ts-config

What Im hoping for is a way to either declare new types in B that are basically copies of the types in C and D, or have A somehow not care about the the compilation issues in its node modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If package B is truly an independent package, then you should only include the compiled `.js` files and `.d.ts` files from B in A (see the `--declaration` flag in [TypeScript's compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) if you aren't currently generating `.d.ts` files). This should avoid TypeScript trying to find typings for C and D.

However, if the interface you're exposing from B includes types from C and D, then things get a little more tricky. You can either:

- Have B declare it's own (equivalent) interfaces as part of its interface, which is correct, since you're hiding C and D from A. C and D are being treated as irrelevant implementation details of B, as far as A is concerned.
- Concede that A actually does need to know about C and D, and include those as part of its dev dependencies.

Comment: The problem is that I am exposing the types from C and D through B. The only issue I have with declaring equivalent interfaces is if the interfaces in C and D change... I guess Ill just have to be very careful when to update the versions.

Comment: It's definitely a software design issue... If B is just some sort of helper library around C and D (which it's sounding like it might be?), it might be better to have A know about C and D or else you're just going to duplicate a lot of type definitions and cause yourself some unnecessary trouble. On the other hand, if B is performing some discrete task, hiding C and D gives you the ability to upgrade or replace C and D in the future without A having to care one bit.